# How do I Inform UPNP to rotate video playback?

Tags: upnp, dlna, upnpx

With UPNP I'm requesting a renderer to play a video, but I need to have the video rotated.

I've looked into metadata, and into the docs, and I've seen how to see what orientations are supported in the device, but I can't figure out how to tell it to rotate the video.

To play the video, I'm posting a SOAPACTION with these parameters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <s:Body>
      <u:Seek xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1">
         <InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
         <Unit>REL_TIME</Unit>
         <Target>00:00:00</Target>
      </u:Seek>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported. You need to decode, rotate and stream video data.